Unable to Publish Instagram Media via API
I've been trying to use the instagram API (API with Instagram Login - Content Publishing) to publish a carousel media container. I followed all the steps as outlined in the documentation (with my instagram account id and access token being taken from my appliaction's Meta Developer website), and was able to create individual Image Containers (where is_carousel_item is true), but as soon as I tried to publish the carousel container (as detailed in step 2 of creating a carousel container), the following error appears:
POST https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/{INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNT_ID}/media
{
    "caption": "...",
    "media_type":"CAROUSEL",
    "children": [<IMG1_ID>,<IMG2_ID>]
}

400 BAD REQUEST
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2207030,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Invalid carousel children",
        "error_user_msg": "The children with IDs <IMG1_ID>, <IMG2_ID>are invalid, non-existent or expired.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AIZShdt_SCAHtmnY2ypXOfm"
    }
}

I tried to check if all the permissions were in order (which they are). The instagram account I'm trying to publish to is under my application's app roles (as an Instagram Tester).
The relevant permissions for content publishing via the Instagram API with Instagram Login are also fulfilled (standard access for instagram_business_basic and instagram_business_content_publish). The access token is included in the requests that I have sent as a Bearer Token in the header.
I also tried to create a single-image media container (which worked - with no is_carousel_item field in JSON), but was unable to publish the it, as shown below:
POST https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/{{INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNT_ID}}/media_publish
{
    "creation_id": <SINGLE_IMG_ID>
}

400 BAD REQUEST
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 24,
        "error_subcode": 2207008,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Media builder not found",
        "error_user_msg": "The media builder with creation ID <SINGLE_IMG_ID> does not exist or has expired.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AMatiUFYiW3iyqFpqVptZFB"
    }
}


The image urls are all hosted on a public AWS S3 bucket, and are publicly available, within the limitations stated in the documentation (.jpg extention file).
When I tried querying for the relevant media container IDs, it will throw an error as well.
I have also tried getting the Instagram Business Login access token through the redirect and callbacks to my server, and used it in my requests to no avail.
{
    "access_token": "IG...",
    "user_id": ...,
    "permissions": [
        "instagram_business_basic",
        "instagram_business_manage_messages",
        "instagram_business_content_publish",
        "instagram_business_manage_comments"
    ]
}


I have been struggling the same issue so far. I have changed the end points and then solved the problem.
Create Container: https://graph.instagram.com/me/media
Poll: https://graph.instagram.com/{container_id}
Publish media: https://graph.instagram.com/me/media_publish
The access_token is the one starts with IG. The image shows you where to get it from.

This information does not exist in the Graph API Documentations. I have found it by trial and error.
Below is my python code that you can use.


import json
import time

import requests
import logging


class InstagramService:
    """
    Service class to handle Instagram Graph API requests for creating and publishing media containers.
    """

    def __init__(self, access_token):
        """
        Initializes the InstagramService with the access token and Instagram account ID.

        Args:
        - access_token (str): The OAuth access token for the Instagram Graph API.
        - instagram_account_id (str): The Instagram account ID.
        """
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.api_url = 'https://graph.instagram.com/'

    async def create_media_container(self, media_type, media_url, caption):
        """
        Creates a media container for the specified media type (image/video).

        Args:
        - media_type (str): The type of media ('IMAGE' or 'VIDEO').
        - media_url (str): The URL of the media file (image or video).
        - caption (str): The caption for the media post (optional).

        Returns:
        - container_id (str): The ID of the created media container.
        """
        logging.info("Creating media container...")

        url = f'{self.api_url}/me/media'
        payload = {
            'access_token': self.access_token,
            'media_type': media_type,
            'caption': caption,
            'video_url': media_url
        }

        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
            response_data = response.json()

            if response.status_code == 200:
                container_id = response_data['id']
                logging.info(f"Media container created with ID: {container_id}")
                return container_id
            else:
                logging.error(f"Error creating media container: {response_data}")
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception occurred while creating media container: {e}")
            return None

    async def check_media_status(self, container_id):
        """
        Checks if the media container is ready to be published.

        Args:
        - container_id (str): The ID of the media container to check.

        Returns:
        - ready (bool): Whether the media container is ready for publishing.
        """
        logging.info(f"Checking media status for container ID: {container_id}...")

        url = f'{self.api_url}{container_id}'
        logging.info("url: {}".format(url))
        params = {
            'access_token': self.access_token,
            'fields': 'status_code'
        }

        try:
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            response_data = response.json()

            if response.status_code == 200:
                status_code = response_data.get('status_code', 'ERROR')
                logging.info(f"Media container status: {status_code}")

                # Check if the container is ready to be published
                if status_code == 'FINISHED':
                    return True
                elif status_code == 'IN_PROGRESS':
                    return False
                else:
                    logging.error(f"Unexpected status code: {status_code}")
                    return None
            else:
                logging.error(f"Error checking media status: {response_data}")
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception occurred while checking media status: {e}")
            return None

    async def wait_for_media_ready(self, container_id, max_minutes=10):
        """
        Polls every minute for 10 minutes to check if the media container is ready to be published.

        Args:
        - container_id (str): The ID of the media container to check.
        - max_minutes (int): The maximum number of minutes to poll (default is 10).

        Returns:
        - ready (bool): Whether the media container is ready for publishing.
        """
        logging.info(f"Waiting for media container {container_id} to be ready...")

        for minute in range(max_minutes):
            ready = await self.check_media_status(container_id)

            if ready is True:
                logging.info(f"Media container {container_id} is ready to be published!")
                return True
            elif ready is False:
                logging.info(f"Media container {container_id} is still processing... waiting for another minute.")
                time.sleep(60)  # Wait for 1 minute before checking again
            else:
                logging.error(f"Error occurred while checking media container status. Stopping the wait.")
                return False

        logging.error(f"Media container {container_id} was not ready after {max_minutes} minutes.")
        return False

    async def publish_media(self, container_id):
        """
        Publishes the created media container on Instagram.

        Args:
        - container_id (str): The ID of the media container to publish.

        Returns:
        - post_id (str): The ID of the published post.
        """
        logging.info(f"Publishing media container with ID: {container_id}...")

        url = f'{self.api_url}/me/media_publish'
        payload = {
            'access_token': self.access_token,
            'creation_id': container_id
        }

        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
            response_data = response.json()

            if response.status_code == 200:
                post_id = response_data['id']
                logging.info(f"Media published successfully with Post ID: {post_id}")
                return post_id
            else:
                logging.error(f"Error publishing media container: {response_data}")
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception occurred while publishing media container: {e}")
            return None

    async def get_rate_limit(self,since):
        """
        Retrieves the current rate limit status for the Instagram Graph API.

        Returns:
        - rate_limit_info (dict): A dictionary containing rate limit details.
        """
        logging.info("Retrieving rate limit information...")

        url = f'{self.api_url}/me/content_publishing_limit'
        params = {
            'access_token': self.access_token,
#            'fields':'quota_usage, quota_usage, rate_limit_settings',
#            'since': since
        }

        try:
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            logging.info(f"Rate limit info retrieved: {response}")

            # Extract rate limit information from headers
            app_usage = response.headers.get('X-App-Usage')
            logging.info("app_usage: {}".format(app_usage))
            if app_usage:
                rate_limit_info = json.loads(app_usage)
                logging.info(f"Rate limit info: {rate_limit_info}")
                return rate_limit_info
            else:
                logging.error("X-App-Usage header not found in the response.")
                return None

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception occurred while retrieving rate limit info: {e}")
            return None



